# Repository as parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I created an Generic dropdown list to use in my controller:

```
GenericDropDownList("myDropDown");

    private void GenericDropDownList(string dropdownName, object selectedDepartment = null) {

    var dropdownQuery = unitOfWork.SalesRepository.Get(orderBy: q => q.OrderBy(d => d.FirstName));

    ViewData[dropdownName] = new SelectList(dropdownQuery, "LastName", "LastName", selectedDepartment);
    }
```

This seems to work fine. What I'm trying is to make the `unitOfWork.TestRepository` dynamic, so that I can use every available repository in the function:

```
GenericDropDownList("myDropDown", SalesRepository);

    private void GenericDropDownList(string dropdownName, object repository, object selectedDepartment = null) {

    var dropdownQuery = repository.Get(orderBy: q => q.OrderBy(d => d.FirstName));

    ViewData[dropdownName] = new SelectList(dropdownQuery, "LastName", "LastName", selectedDepartment);
    }
```

The above doesn't work. I get the following error:

> Error CS1061  'object' does not contain a definition for 'Get' and no
>   extension method 'Get' accepting a first argument of type 'object'
>   could be found

Is it possible to make the dropdown as dynamic as I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class `object` does not have a `.Get` method so it makes sense that this does not compile.

Using `dynamic` will fix that because then `.Get` is resolved at runtime, albeit at a performance cost, and with risk of a runtime error if `.Get` does not exist at runtime.

The best approach in my opinion is to use an interface:

```
private void GenericDropDownList(string dropdownName, IRepository repository, object selectedDepartment = null)
{
    // ...
}
```

When using Entity Framework you can impose this interface on the Repository classes by using partial classes:

```
public partial class ThisRepository : IRepository
{
}

public partial class ThatRepository : IRepository
{
}
```

A catch will be that an interface can *not* define a property such as `FirstName`, so you either have to define a method for that, or use a `Func<IRepository, string>` for the sorting bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a dynamic object use the `dynamic` type.

Or try casting it to an appropriate type:

```
(repository as type).Get(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct approach would be to have all your repositories implement a common interface with common methods.

For example, you can create the interface `IRepository`, or `IRepository<TSource>` if you want it to be a little more specific.

The problem is that `TSource` should have a `FirstName` property according to your expected code.

**Are you sure that all repositories will have entities with `FirstName` property?**

If the answer is *no*, then you cannot create such generic method (You'd need to redefine your logic, or create a specific interface that will have entities with this property, but you won't be able to pass in **any** repository, only the ones that implement this interface).

If the answer is *yes*, then you can create a *base class* for all your source entities (`BaseEntity`, for instance), which would have the `FirstName` property.

Supposing the answer was yes, then you can change your method's signature to:

```
private void GenericDropDownList(string dropdownName, IRepository<TSource> repository, object selectedDepartment = null) where TSource : BaseEntity
```

You would then be able to call it:

```
GenericDropDownList("myDropDown", SalesRepository); //SalesRepository should implement IRepository<Sale>, where Sale : BaseEntity
```